# Pop-Up User Form To Select Non Empty Columns Selects Empty Ones

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that is organized within a main sheet.  Every item has 3 rows.  These items are grouped and sub-grouped by row and columns.

I have developed several reporting options. These reports identify certain items based upon characteristics in the main sheet and copy them over to another sheet.  So far, so good.

My final task would appear simple and based upon prior logic I developed.  I need a pop-up window that prompts the user for a column.  Based upon the column input, I grab all rows that are not empty (in their corresponding groups of 3) and copy them over.  As I indicated, this logic worked previously.  I leave a blank row between the groups for easy reading.

I take the column input and translate to column number (thanks to you and a previous post!).  The problem is that the code copies over the groups correctly (with non-blank entries), and then once it leaves the first row grouping, it starts copying over non-blank entries.

I know what the entries will be in these columns and also tried using a key method - converting the known entries to ascii and checking cell value against that.  Still, the same result.

I am wondering if the problem is the fact that the code resides in the userform?  Do I need to separate the userform from the macro?  Is columnNumber somehow getting overwritten (it appears that way).  There may be artifacts (unused variables) from previous versions and troublshooting...

I grant this is not the most elegant coding I've done, but I am running out of time (I only have a few days left for this entire project).  Here it is, and ANY advice or help is greatly appreciated.  THANK YOU well in advance :)

```
Private Sub Cancel_Click()

UserForm4.Hide

End Sub

Private Sub Go_Click()
    Dim Test As String
    Dim colNumber, columnNumber As Integer
    Dim m As Integer
    Dim ws2 As String
    Dim i, j, k, r As Integer
    Dim BlankRow2
    Dim ColorCode As Integer
    Dim RqtRow As Integer
    Dim Item As Integer
    Dim ColVal, AscCol As String
    Dim Row1Value, Row2Value, Row3Value As Integer

    ' Initialize Variables
    ws1 = "Requirements_Matrix"
    ws2 = "OUTPUT"
    RqtRow = 8
    BlankRow2 = 4
    Item = BlankRow2
    Lastrow1 = Sheets(ws1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Lastcol1 = Sheets(ws1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Lastrow2 = Sheets(ws2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Lastcol2 = Sheets(ws2).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Test = UserForm4.WhichTest.Value
    If Test <> "" Then
        colLetter = UCase(Test)
        colNumber = 0
        For m = 1 To Len(colLetter)
            colNumber = colNumber + (Asc(Mid(colLetter, Len(colLetter) - m + 1, 1)) - 64) * 26 ^ (m - 1)
        Next
        columnNumber = colNumber
        If (columnNumber < 24) Or (columnNumber > 136) Then
           UserForm5.Show 'outside test columns - do not have time to execute further error testing...
        Else 'Copy requirements from Requirements_Matrix Sheet to Output Sheet
            With Sheets(ws2)
              Sheets(ws2).Select
              Rows("4:5000").Select
              Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
           End With

        Sheets(ws1).Select
           For i = 8 To Lastrow1  'find non-empty cells
              If Sheets(ws1).Cells(i, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 34 Then
                  Row3Value = Sheets(ws1).Cells(i, 3).Value
              End If

            If Sheets(ws1).Cells(i, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 44 Then
              Row2Value = Sheets(ws1).Cells(i, 2).Value
            End If

            If Sheets(ws1).Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 37 Then
              Row1Value = Sheets(ws1).Cells(i, 1).Value
            End If

           If Sheets(ws1).Cells(i, 5) = "Requirement" Then 'Requirement Row
              RqtRow = i
           End If

           If (Sheets(ws1).Cells(i, columnNumber).Value <> Empty) And _
           Sheets(ws1).Cells(i, 3).Interior.ColorIndex <> 34 And _
           Sheets(ws1).Cells(i, 2).Interior.ColorIndex <> 44 And _
           Sheets(ws1).Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> 37 Then
               k = RqtRow + 2
               Increment = BlankRow2 + 2
               Sheets(ws1).Select
                 Rows(RqtRow & ":" & k).Select  'select requirement block containing non-blank cell
                 Selection.Copy

                 Sheets(ws2).Select
                 Range(BlankRow2 & ":" & Increment).Select
                 ActiveSheet.Paste
                 ActiveSheet.Cells(BlankRow2, 1).Value = Row1Value
                 ActiveSheet.Cells(BlankRow2, 2).Value = Row2Value
                 ActiveSheet.Cells(BlankRow2, 3).Value = Row3Value

                BlankRow2 = Increment + 2 'leave a blank row between requirements

             End If
         Next

      End If
    Else
       UserForm5.Show
    End If
    UserForm4.WhichTest.Value = Empty
    UserForm4.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried doing `<> ""` rather than `<> Empty`?

Comment: Thanks for responding... unfortunately, yes.  That was the first thing I tried.  All the cells are formatted, so I wondered if it was pulling in these cells based upon formatting (borders, fill, etc.).  That is why I tried positive matching against what I *know* the content only *could* be (one of 8 values).  The same thing happened.  It kind of worked.  It pulled over the rows matching the "keys" then went ahead and started pulling over rows with blanks..

Comment: I took the above logic and pasted it into a separate macro.  I hard-coded the (column) input.  Each time I ran it, it executed correctly.  I think it has to do with the logic being embedded in the userform(?)  If this is the case, do I simply declare the userform input as a global variable and call a separate macro?

Comment: Public/global variable is one option. Second is to pass value directly when calling that sub which should be one with argument(s).

Comment: Thank you very much!  Troubleshooting by isolating the code into a macro and hardcoding the value was helpful.  I knew the logic (while not elegant) at least worked.  I defined a sub within the userform and passed the argument ByVal and reassigned it to a local within the sub.  All is good.  I am relieved it works!  Thank you again for solid direction!!!